# Warning: (vsim-8634) Code was not compiled with coverage options

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-dpi

I am trying to run a UVM simulation and I use a C code for predicting the output but I get the warning mentioned above when running the simulation.
Will this warning affect the test?
Note : I didn't put the importing file for C code in a module. I put it in class.

```
import "DPI-C" function void something();
class c;
...
endclass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning does not affect your simulation and most likely has nothing to with the code shown. You can type `verror 8634` to get a better explanation of the error message.